# Glidecam focus control

Tags: dslr, canon

Is there puller for controlling the lens focus when using a glidecam? Is there also something similar for the zoom, in case it's a zoom lens?

I have not found anything off the shelf that I can buy online.

Comment: Have you tried a search on google, vimeo, and youtube for DIY lens puller or follow focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything specifically made for use with a glidecam.  My impression of most stabilization systems is that you still operate the camera directly, you just are not supporting it without the stabilization.  I'm not aware of any follow focus/pull systems that are designed specifically for use with a gimble or gimble and spring-arm stabilization system.